# Error in d3.js after upgrading to Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, angular8

I have updated my **Angular 4** app to **Angular 8**. Application works fine in dev build but breaks in prod build. I get the following error when loading the application.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
>       at d3.js:8
>       at Object../node_modules/d3/d3.js (d3.js:9554)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/pages/home/dashboard/map/map.component.ts (main-es2015.js:9841)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/pages/home/home.routes.ts (home.routes.ts:2)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/pages/home/home.module.ts (home.event.bus.ts:5)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)

And my **tsconfig.json** file looks like this.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
  "importHelpers": true,
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es2015",
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom"
  ],
  "module": "esnext",
  "paths": {
    "core-js/es7/reflect": ["../node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect- 
     metadata"],
    "core-js/es6/*": ["../node_modules/core-js/es/*"]
  }
 }
}
```

I tried changing the target from **es2015** to **es5** with no success and gave me an error in vendor.js
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the target in **tsconfig.json** file from **es2015** to **es5**. d3 library is not compatible with es2015 as of yet.

And that in return throws an error in d3.js because of the use of UTF-8 symbols such as π. To fix that you can specify the UTF-8 charset on the HTML host document.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. With Angular 7 it was possible to target es2016/es2017 which obviously worked with d3. Now after upgrading to Angular 8 that no longer works. This either means that Angular 7 did not include d3 in compilation, but does so now in v8, or that Angular 8 has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 decided to put `type="module"` to the index.html when you target es2015+. In my example I used es2017 successfully with Angular 7, of course including d3 (via plotly.js). I haven't found any solution except to modify the dist/index.html once it's changed. For me this is a perfectly working solution as the generated code works fine.

To do the same, install first https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack and configure it like they describe it. After creating the extra-webpack.config.js you put in this file following code:

```
class FixIndex {
  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  done() {
    const path = __dirname + '/dist/' + this.path;
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
        console.log('path not found', path);
        return;
    }
    let file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    file = file.replace(/type="module"/g, '');

    fs.writeFileSync(path, file);
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap(
        'FixIndex',
        () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.done();
            }, 1);
        }
    );
  }
}

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new FixIndex('deepkit/index.html'),
  ],
}
```