# d3v5 Angular 8 production mode - ERROR TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

Tags: angular, d3.js

D3v5 functions work fine in development mode but throwing run time errors in production mode

> ERROR TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

Type script code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {timeFormat} from 'd3-time-format';
...
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(){
    var formatTime = timeFormat("%B %d, %Y");
   console.log('Time parser :: ', formatTime(new Date))
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "d3": "^5.13.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

tsconfig.json - Also tried updating the target as per [Error in d3.js after upgrading to Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141011/error-in-d3-js-after-upgrading-to-angular-8)

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    **"target": "es5",**
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ..
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": ..
}
```

Any suggestion or leads will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you happen to find any working solution for this issue? I'm also facing the same.

Comment: I had to bump the versions, below you will find the ones which worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone encountering similar issue I was able to make it work by bumping d3 and angular to the below versions

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "d3": "^5.14.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

After updating the @angular-devkit/build-angular  version from

> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2"

to

> "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.17"

works for me.

Comment: Due to some issue with angular it breaks the third party library in optimization, so works by updating build angular version