# d3v5 Angular 6 Universal - ERROR TypeError: (void 0) is not a function

Tags: angular

I run `d3` in normal mode (ng serve) and everything works fine, but when I pass through `angular universal`, I find there are many problems and I can't draw the chart normally.

I checked the relevant information and it seems that each version will encounter similar problems:
[angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58898594/d3v5-angular-8-production-mode-error-typeerror-void-0-is-not-a-function)
[angular 4](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/44988485-error-typeerror-void-0-is-not-a-function-using-systemjs-and-latest-version)

I tried to change several versions of the module(ex:`@angular-devkit/build-angular`), but none were successful. Simply updating some module will cause the entire angular to not work properly.

My `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "csspin": "^1.1.4",
    "d3": "^5.14.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
    "npm": "^6.12.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.112",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.54",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.5",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.8.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
  }
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Updating angular to 8 resolved it.

Comment: @Arcteezy Does it work under universal? I tried to update to angular 8, but more problems occurred and I couldn't solve it.